# CSS jigsaw piece creation

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create the jigsaw pieces stitched together but not able to achieve the exact shape like below

[image: Jigsaw pieces with text]

Currently, I am struck with the below code but not able to achieve the shape
The HTML and CSS code and achieved the design provided below.

```
<div class="row " style="margin: 0px 5px;">
    <div class="col-md bg-color-1">
       <p>Some text goes here</p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md bg-color-2">
         <div class="puzzle"></div>
         <p>Some text goes there</p>
     </div>
</div>
#CSS
.puzzle {
    position: absolute;
    left: -27px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,55,55,.25);
    border-top-left-radius: 99px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 99px;
    border-top-right-radius: 70px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 70px;
    border-left: 3px solid #ff3737;
    border-top: 3px solid #ff3737;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff3737;
}
.bg-color-2 {
    background-color: rgba(255,55,55,.25);
    border-top: 2px solid #ff3737;
    border-right: 2px solid #ff3737;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff3737;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 250px;
}
.bg-color-2 {
    background-color: rgba(255,55,55,.25);
    border-top: 2px solid #ff3737;
    border-right: 2px solid #ff3737;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff3737;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 250px;
}
```

[image]
How to get rid of the line at the verge of the two pieces and also getting the curves in the junction?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: so, what do you want us to do, fix the width? the text color? what?

Comment: Actually there is a darkened border at the verge. That's need to tackled. Putting this up in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't for me well so I just quickly created this code. 
If you see I created one class called `.circle` and just add the `z-index: -1;` 
So basically there are two boxes in your code and if you just adjust `z-index` you'll get the output. Make sure that the left side box has the higher number of z-index and circle has little lower than left box and the right box ( purple in your case) goes low so it has lowest z-index number.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.half-circle {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.box {
  margin-left: 5%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="half-circle"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
  </div>
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: the background-color with alpha values for the extra circular piece and main div will create the
issue.
Here without using alpha value that issue will not arise.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't helped you out, I searched and worked more than an half hour but didn't find the solution, I guess you have simply use RGB not RGBA. Sorry again.

Comment: No problem mate. It needs a bit of expertise. Using RGB is not currently on papers.